# How particular pixel to transparent in opencv python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I have image **messi.jpeg** .I want to replace pixel with color  (0,111,111) to transparent in **messi.jpeg**.
now. my code is give below.

```
 img[np.where((img == [0,111,111]).all(axis = 2))] = [255,255,255]
```

I want transparent pixel. now it converted to white

Answer (score 7):

For those arriving from Google the above answer may have been true at the time it was written but [as the docs describe it is no longer accurate](http://docs.opencv.org/master/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imread). Passing a negative value to imread returns an array with an alpha channel.

In python this does the job:

```
>>> im = cv2.imread('sunny_flat.png', -1)
>>> im
array([[[ 51,  44,  53, 255],
    [ 46,  40,  46, 255],
    [ 40,  31,  36, 255],
    ..., 
    [ 24,  26,  36, 255],
    [ 26,  28,  39, 255],
    [ 15,  17,  27, 255]]], dtype=uint8)
>>> im[0][0] = np.array([0,0,0,0], np.uint8)
>>> im
array([[[  0,   0,   0,   0],
    [ 46,  40,  46, 255],
    [ 40,  31,  36, 255],
    ..., 
    [ 24,  26,  36, 255],
    [ 26,  28,  39, 255],
    [ 15,  17,  27, 255]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: this limits to those PNGs that originally has alpha channels. For those PNGs with RGB channels only, alpha channel has to be added beforehand.

Answer (score 4):

**OpenCV doesn't support transparency** (natively), sorry.

One approach is to [add another channel to the image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7724894/176769) to represent the alpha channel. However, OpenCV can't display RGBA images, so upon loading an [RGBA image ignore the 4th channel](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3288/problem-reading-png-with-transparency-layer/?answer=3290#post-id-3290) to display it correctly.