# Translucent objects on IplImage

Tags: c++, opencv, iplimage

I draw objects on `IplImage` like this:

```
cvLine(image, point_1, point_2, color, thickness, CV_AA); // Line
cvCircle(mage, point, radius, color, thickness, CV_AA); // Circle
// and some others...
```

How can I draw them translucent? `cv::Scalar` does not support alpha channel,  if I understand correctly. I found something similar, but not quite appropriate: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722296/opencv-adding-transparency-to-iplimage). Here we are talking about translucenty `IplImage`, not about the objects on it.

Comment: From OpenCV 2.4.13.7 documentation [Drawing Function](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html): _**Note:** The functions do not support alpha-transparency when the target image is 4-channel. In this case, the `color[3]` is simply copied to the repainted pixels. Thus, if you want to paint semi-transparent shapes, you can paint them in a separate buffer and then blend it with the main image._

Comment: also, if you use C++ **do not** use the C API is deprecated. i.e. IplImage should be `cv::Mat` and `cvLine` should be `cv::line` and so on. cv::Scalar has 4 values, I do not see a problem of it supporting Alpha, maybe is the drawing function per se as HansHirse pointed out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I tested it now with `IplImage` and `cv::Mat`, and both `cvCircle` and `cv::circle` don't support drawing semi-transparent objects. I used OpenCV 3.4.0, since this version still supports the old C API.

Let's have a look at the following code:

```cpp
// IplImage - doesn't work
IplImage* ipl = cvCreateImage(cvSize(201, 201), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
cvSet(ipl, CvScalar(255, 0, 0, 255));
cvCircle(ipl, CvPoint(100, 100), 50, CvScalar(0, 0, 255, 128), CV_FILLED);

// cv::Mat - doesn't work
cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(201, 201, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255));
cv::circle(img, cv::Point(100, 100), 50, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255, 128), cv::FILLED);
```

We create a blue 4-channel image with zero transparency, and draw a red circle with 0.5 transparency. In both cases, we get the following output:

[image: False output]

We see, that the part of red circle actually "replaces" the pixel values in the original blue image.

So, for `IplImage` as well as for `cv::Mat` we need to use blending, e.g. using [`addWeighted`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gafafb2513349db3bcff51f54ee5592a19). Let's have a look at this code:

```cpp
// IplImage - works
IplImage* iplBG = cvCreateImage(cvSize(201, 201), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
cvSet(iplBG, CvScalar(255, 0, 0));
IplImage* iplFG = cvCreateImage(cvSize(201, 201), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
cvSet(iplFG, CvScalar(0, 0, 0));
cvCircle(iplFG, CvPoint(100, 100), 50, CvScalar(0, 0, 255), CV_FILLED);
IplImage* iplOut = cvCreateImage(cvSize(201, 201), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
cvAddWeighted(iplBG, 1, iplFG, 0.5, 0, iplOut);

// cv::Mat - works
cv::Mat imgBG = cv::Mat(201, 201, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0));
cv::Mat imgFG = cv::Mat(201, 201, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
cv::circle(imgFG, cv::Point(100, 100), 50, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), cv::FILLED);
cv::Mat imgOut;
cv::addWeighted(imgBG, 1, imgFG, 0.5, 0, imgOut);
```

In fact, we create a blue 3-channel background image like this:

[image: Background]

And, we create a black foreground 3-channel image of the same size with the red circle:

[image: Foreground]

Using `addWeighted` with `alpha = 1` and `beta = 0.5`, we get the expected output for both versions:

[image: Correct output]